# Docker:Error Response from daemon timeout

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, docker

I installed Oracle Virtual Box on my laptop that has Window 10 home. Then I installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Xenial as well as docker. Docker is working fine but I am facing one issue. When I am running following command, its giving me error.

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

- Error screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

- Ubuntu network settings:

[image: Ubuntu network settings]

- Check dockerd:

Running ps -ef | grep docker and docker system info shows me the following screenshot. The registry shown by system info is https://index.docker.io/v1/:
[image: Check dockerd:]

Appreciate it if anyone can help me with this problem. Is my networking configuration wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell; 1) you have no `hello-word:latest` image locally so it tries to get one from some external registry and 2) when trying to resolve the name of registry, the DNS (which on Ubuntu is really 127.0.0.1, your own system) doesn't answer. Can you resolve other names in the Ubuntu VM (for instance `ping www.google.com`)?

Comment: Hi xenoid. My ping to www.google.com fails and I realised I have no access to the Internet anymore via the mozilla firefox. It is strange as I was able to access earlier on with the default network configuration using NAT..